# Найти элемент div с текстом содержащим странные символы

Tags: javascript, html

На странице сайта появляется Советник, который предлагает Похожие товары.
Заблокировать элемент по id или классу невозможно, так как они генерируются рандомно.
Но сейчас можно использовать поиск элемента по содержимому.
И тут возникла проблема, так как тег выглядит следующим образом:

```html
<div class="KwuZ8HZqOFKQZKOzo3Si">По&zwnj;x&zwnj;oжи&zwnj;e&zwnj; &zwnj;тo&zwnj;в&zwnj;a&zwnj;p&zwnj;ы</div>
```

Для поиска использую регулярное выражение, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы находился только этот элемент, иначе можно случайно удалить лишнее. Как это можно сделать?

Моё текущее решение (нужно доработать):

```js
        var regex = /П.+?о.+?х.+?о.+?ж.+?и.+?е.+?т.+?о.+?в.+?а.+?р.+?ы/;

        var divElements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

        for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
            var element = divElements[i];
            var textContent = element.textContent || element.innerText;

            if (regex.test(textContent)){
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                attempts = 0;
            }
        }
```

Дополню, чтобы было понятно.
Такой поиск может найти, например, тег с таким текстом: **п**р**охожие** ис**то**птали **ва**ленками всю **ры**бу
Мне это не подходит

PS
Можно было бы скопировать текст со спец символами и сделать поиск, но при перезагрузке страницы невидимые символы меняются.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает текущее решение?

Comment: Находит лишние теги, которые содержат символы в такой же последовательности, но с другим текстом. 
Например: прохожие истоптали валенками всю рыбу. 
Такой текст явно не должен удаляться

Comment: Если элемент создаётся в одном и том-же месте DOM, то может быть отслеживать его появление с помощью MutationObserver?

Answer (score 0):

К вашему регулярному выражению, добавьте дополнительную проверку, что в данной строке есть спец символ **‌**

```
const regSymbol = /.*?\u200C.*?$/g;

// Ваш код 

if (regex.test(textContent) && regSymbol.test(textContent)){
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    attempts = 0;
}
```

В таком случае, удалятся только те div, в которых существует нужная вам последовательность символов и присутствует указанный спец символ

Comment: Спасибо, это значительно помогло продвинуться в задаче. Осталось только протестировать

Answer (score 0):

Исходная строка значительно более загрязнена, чем кажется, и, наверное, будет генерироваться с вставкой различных новых загрязнителей. Кроме "нормальных" символов есть различные виды пробелов, а также спецсимволы вида &***;, а также замена русских букв на латинские. Для отладки в коде ниже выводятся символы с кодами - видно, что, например, x имеет код 120 - это латинская х, ее нужно заменить русской (х = 1093), и так далее.

Ниже код вычищает с помощью трех регулярных выражений (спецсимволы, пробелы, замена букв) и в итоге сравнивает со строкой 'Похожие товары'.

```js
function char_codes(text) {
    str = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < textContent.length; i++) {
        s = textContent.charAt(i)
        scode = textContent.charCodeAt(i)
        str += `(${s} = ${scode})`
    }
    return str
}

divElements = ['По&zwnj;x&zwnj;oжи&zwnj;e&zwnj; &zwnj;тo&zwnj;в&zwnj;a&zwnj;p&zwnj;ы']

const rep = {'o': 'о', 'x': 'х', 'e': 'е', 'a': 'а', 'p': 'р'}

for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
    var textContent = divElements[i];
    console.log(char_codes(textContent), '\n')
    textContent = divElements[i].replaceAll(/&[a-z]+;/gi, "").replaceAll(/\s+/gi, ' ').replaceAll(/[oxeap]/gi, x => rep[x]);
    console.log(char_codes(textContent), '\n')

    if (textContent === 'Похожие товары') {
        console.log(textContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это значительно помогло продвинуться в задаче. Дополню проверкой на отсутствие спец символов, так как такое не нужно будет удалять и перейду к тестированию